# How do you get the object name when using SimpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

If the format is the following, where c is an object array that I must foreach through each iteration:

```
$a->b->c
```

And I do:

```
$z = $a->b
foreach($z as $key => $value)
echo $value['field'];
```

$key comes up as null, even though I have valid values. How do I get the name of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the following piece of XML and the code to load it with SimpleXML :

```
$str = <<<XML
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>glop</c>
            <d>test</d>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
```

You could "cast" `$xml->a->b` to an array, to be able to iterate over it :

```
foreach ((array)$xml->a->b as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name : $value<br />";
}
```

And you'll get this kind of output :

```
c : glop
d : test
```

*(maybe not exactly the same XML string as yours, but I hope this will help you get to the solution -- if it does, can you edit your question to show us you XML data, and the output you'll willing to get ? )*

Quoting the manual page, at the [Converting to array section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) :

> If an object is converted to an array,
>   the result is an array whose elements
>   are the object's properties.
> The keys
>   are the member variable names, with a
>   few notable exceptions: integer
>   properties are unaccessible; private
>   variables have the class name
>   prepended to the variable name;
>   protected variables have a '*'
>   prepended to the variable name.

Comment: This is an object that is using ArrayAccess. I'm not sure that your solution would work for it.

Comment: Hu ; you mean it has nothing to do with SimpleXML ? (there is "simplexml" in the title of your question, so I might kinda have taken quite a shortcut ^^ )

Comment: It is using simpleXML, the object is an object that implements the ArrayAccess interface, and your answer was actually correct :)

Adding (array) to the front of my foreach caused my $key to get the correct value, instead of returning a NULL value.

Comment: OK -- thanks for the clarification :-) I have to admit I had a moment of doubt ^^ ;; have fun !

Answer (score 6):

XML:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c />
    <d />
    <e />
  </b>
</a>
```

PHP Code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file_url, true);
foreach($xml->b->children() as $node) {
    echo $node->getName() . "\n";
}
```

Would give you:

```
c
d
b
```

See [PHP's manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) for further reference.

Comment: This is a more elegant and OO based solution utilizing SimpleXML better.